# Does logging onto WoW Mobile Armory app show that you have logged into the game?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If I log into the mobile armory app, can someone see that I've logged into my account if they are playing the actual game?

Comment: I don't remember what the state of the chat part of mobile armory was like and I don't play anymore, but if you're logged into mobile chat in the armory application then you will show on your guild's member list as online via mobile chat, but will not appear to anybody on your realid list or anybody outside of your guild.

Comment: @kalina That's what I thought. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you log in to the mobile chat feature, then you appear logged into "Remote chat" to members of your guild in the guild roster. However, you do not appear logged into the game, don't show up on friend lists, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only the people in your guild will be able to see you in the guild chat

Comment: @Orbas That's what I said!